# Ubuntu amd64 instead of i386 - cause for slow booting?

Tags: boot, 16.04, 64-bit, 32-bit

When trying to find out why my laptop takes 2 minutes to boot I noticed I have the `amd64` version of Ubuntu 16.04 installed instead of the `i386` version which would be the appropriate one for using my Intel i5 processor.

Is it problematic to use the amd64 version with an Intel processor and can I switch to the `i386` version without loosing files from my home directory?

Could this be the reason why Ubuntu is booting so slow?

Comment: You should give us your laptop make and model number. My guess is since it's an i5 ideal booting time from HDD is 45 seconds and from SSD is 15 seconds or less.

Comment: Yes, i 'm sure it shouldn't be booting that slow, especially because i am using an SSD for booting. I will try some other things and post a new question if i cant figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: `amd64` is the correct choice for Intel i5 CPU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, `i386` is for 32-bit CPUs. `amd64` is for 64-bit CPUs, like your i5. There is never a speed difference when on a 64-bit CPU.

**DO NOT** switch to the i386 version of Ubuntu. It will, in some cases, actually slow your computer down further by limiting it to 2 GB of RAM.

Comment: 32 bit software can only address 4 GB of RAM. 64 bit software can address 16 million Terabytes of RAM. Obviously the more RAM you have makes a big speed difference. With 16 million Terabytes of RAM I can store 1 million 160 GB hard drives in RAM. Or something like that... I haven't written that new calculator I talked about 5 years ago yet.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix The speed difference is generally negligible, especially in Ubuntu. OP specifically stated that he is running the AMD64 version of Ubuntu *on a 64-bit CPU*.

Comment: perhaps you are right but on my 4GB Toshiba 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04 uses 1 GB of RAM and on my 8 GB Dell 64-bit Ubuntu 16.04 uses 4.87 GB of RAM just now. I think the amount of RAM and therefor 64-bit addressing of it makes a difference somewhere some how.

Comment: Either way there's no point in using 32-bit nowadays (unless the hardware is 32-bit only, of course). The 32-bit architecture will die sooner than most people realize. It has been *rumored* Canonical will drop it with 18.04 or 18.10. Just a rumor, of course, but I'm willing to bet real money (or a dinner at Jamie Oliver's Fifteen - London) it won't survive the next decade (except maybe in niche distros).

Comment: @CelticWarrior I totally agree with you. ARM will fill the niche gap for x86 processors, and Intel/AMD x64 will fill in the rest.